# is there any way to get the object from its property?

Tags: python, oop

I want to list the objects by its attribute, and get it with only the attributes that is in the list.

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id=id

a=foo(0)
b=foo(1)

ids=[a.id,b.id]
```

can I refer to `a` with only having `ids` ?

and if it is not possible this way, how can I ?

Comment: Why not use a dictionary here?

Comment: you are right. but it is an example for demonstrating. I will use multiple attributes.

Comment: The keys would be the `id`s, the values can be whatever you need them to be (i.e. `foo` *objects*). As long as the objects are in a dict, then you can always do a lookup easily.

Comment: yea I get it. but I just wonder, is there any way to do it with the way I want ? like getting the player who fired the bullet ? without adding the bullet to a dictionary and marking its shooter

Comment: It can be done other ways too, e.g. if you store all your `foo` objects in a `list` and then lookup the list, but that seems less logical here. You can also potentially make use of `locals()` -- but don't do that. Just use a dictionary for this.

Comment: I understood the ways you serve. but I wanna know is there any way to get the object from its property? not for particularly this eg.

Comment: @FLAW no, objects don't magically keep track of other objects that reference it ([ok, not exactly true](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html)). *That's your job* Either using an independent object that keeps track of the relationship (e.g. a dict) or the objects can reference each other (can get messy, but sometimes works fine, e.g. a doubly-linked list)

Answer (score 0):

User a dictionary:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id=id


a=foo(0)
b=foo(1)

ids={a.id:a, b.id:b}
print(ids[0])
```

### An example without a dictionary

**NOTE**: This may be better achieved using a Meta-programming in Python, and your question may seem that can have an actual real world usage when creating Python Packages, Frameworks etc.

Still, in a clumsy way it does achieve this.

```
import random

class foo:
    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id=id


def create_counter():
    count = 0
    def internal():
        nonlocal count
        count += 1
        return count
    return internal

counter = create_counter()

def create_id():
    """Generate random id, uses a stateles Closure to keep track of counter"""

    id_ = None
    name = 'class_'
    id_gen = str(hex(random.randrange(1000)))       
    id_ =  name + str(counter()) + "_" + id_gen[2:]        

    return id_


def change_name_ref(inst_obj):
    """Change Instance Name to Instance ID"""
    inst_obj.__name__ = inst_obj.id



a = foo(create_id()) # --> Assign a radnom Id 
b = foo(create_id())
c = foo('class_1_15b')

change_name_ref(a)
change_name_ref(b)
change_name_ref(c)

ids = [a, b, c]


def get_instance(inst_list, target):
 
    for idx, id_ in enumerate(inst_list):
        if id_.__name__ == target:
            inst = inst_list[idx]
            print(f'Here The Class instance {inst}, ID: {inst.id}')


value = get_instance(ids, 'class_1_15b')

# Here The Class instance <__main__.foo object at 0x7f6988f016d0>, ID: class_1_15b
```

Comment: yea it is totally does what we need here and many situations. but it was just an example for telling you what I want to do. the thing I wanna know is, is there any way to get the object from its property?

Comment: OK, yes I was looking at the above comments, is hard to understand what you mean,I mean it seems that is not something that someone does. But Iam thinking about it.

Comment: Maybe if you give a bigger picture of what you are trying to do it would make more sense? You asking this just to know in general , or because would be better in what you are implementing?

Comment: in past, once I needed. and I just remembered that. since that time, I still don't know how to do that. so it is why I ask.
and for a implementing, I would like to learn how can I store the bullets' shooter ? still dict is the best ?

Comment: @FLAW If Id aren't only numbers, then I may think a way, but again I see if is working but is not someone would do, both for readability and performance (Dictionary look up are really fast) any way hold on